# Lua : add a table in a table

Tags: insert, lua, lua-table

I recently started learning Lua and I have a question about tables :

```
local mytable = {10,11,12}
```

I would add another table in `mytable[3]` , if I do this :

```
table.insert(mytable[3], {[15] = {}})
```

Will it works ?

And if it works, what will be the "final" result ?

```
mytable[3][15] = {}
```

or

```
mytable[3][1][15] = {}
```

?

It's probably a basic question but it will help me :p

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first argument of `table.insert` should be the table being inserted, so the correct syntax is:

```
table.insert(mytable, {[15] = {}})
```

After this, the value of `mytable[4]` (note that Lua table index starts from `1`) is the table `{[15] = {}}`, and the value of `mytable[4][15]` is therefore an empty table.

---

To make `mytable[3]` a table `{[15] = {}}`, use assignment instead:

```
mytable[3] = {[15] = {}}
```

Comment: Ok, but if I want to have  `mytable[3][15] = {}` how can I do this ?

Comment: @unknown Assign the value: `mytable[3] = {[15] = {}}`, note that this will overwrite the previous value of `mytable[3]` (the number `12`)

Comment: And if I want to keep all the other values, it's possible ?

Comment: @unknown No, `mytable[3]` can't have both values, it doesn't make sense.

Comment: Yes, but I want to have this `mytable[3][15] = {}` and another `mytable[3][VALUE] = {}` because my script needs many values of `mytable[X][XX] = {}` (I don't know if you understand ^^)

Comment: @unknown That's OK, if `mytable[3]` is a table, you can have `mytable[3][VALUE]` for each unique value of `VALUE`(except `nil`). I was talking about the code `local mytable = {10,11,12}`, after this, `mytable[3]` is `12`, not a table.

Comment: Yes it was just an exemple, my final table should be like this : `mytable[number1][number2] = value` and `mytable[number1]["default"] = value` . Sorry if I don't speak english very well, i'm french ^^